# Awkward missing partial in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, partial

Can anyone explain, why is my _index.html.haml:

```
= render '/shared/datepicker'
```

throwing this exception:

> ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial shared/_datepicker with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee, :haml]}

and

```
= paginate @graphs.list.data
= render '/shared/datepicker'
```

is not throwing anything?

paginate is Kaminari method and there is nothing more in the file, shared/_datepicker.html.erb really exists

Comment: It looks like you're making a JSON request; are you?

Comment: I think yes .. I can set remote: false or remote: true, but it makes no difference